# Use C# to Save an Excel File Contained in a Tableau API Response

Tags: c#, excel, encoding, tableau-api

I'm trying to download an Excel file from a Tableau view, using a snippet based on this article: [Downloading Files with the WebRequest and WebResponse Classes](https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/downloading-files-with-the-webrequest-and-webresponse-classes/).

```
WebResponse response = null;
Stream webStream = null;
Stream localStream   = null;
  
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", token);

response = request.GetResponse();
webStream = response.GetResponseStream();

localStream = File.Create("testing.xlsx");
byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
int bytesRead;

int bytesProcessed = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = webStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead > 0);

response.Close();
webStream.Close();
localStream.Close();
```

But when I try to open the Excel file it says "Nope, maybe it is corrupt?". The response is a complete Excel file "ready to be saved", which means that it's encoded using UTF-8. Indeed, if I use Postman to do the call, and then save the response, it's saved and opens without any problem.

Before finding the page I said above, I thought the problem was because the response is UTF-8 and the class *String* is UTF-16. So, I made some testing getting the data from the file generated by Postman and then writing to a new file. The result of the testings: indeed, if the data passes through a String, it's not well saved. Then I tried with that code, and got the same result: fail. I'm pretty sure this code is not using any UTF-16 encoding variable, but maybe I'm wrong.

Anyway, do anyone knows what is my problem with that code, or point me to the right way to accomplish my task? That is, to download a Tableau report to Excel, using the Tableau API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're stuck on a particularly old version of .NET, that referenced link is from 2004. The following code will work in .NET 5 / C# 9, and in earlier versions with just some minor tweaking of the `using` statements. It's showing for Tableau Online, but should work fine for recent versions of Server, if I had to guess. This is sample-grade code, so I would recommend [following best practices for the HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) if you intend to make this call frequently.

```
//using System.IO;
//using System.Net.Http;

var token = "your-session-token";
var uri = "https://your-pod.online.tableau.com/api/.../sites/.../views/.../crosstab/excel";
var yourFile = "D:/file/test.xlsx";

using var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
request.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", token);
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
using FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(yourFile, FileMode.Create);
await response.Content.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
```

UPDATE: If you're constrained to WebRequest and non-async methods, you can try the following:

```
var token = "your-session-token";
var uri = "https://your-pod.online.tableau.com/api/.../sites/.../views/.../crosstab/excel";
var yourFile = "D:/file/test.xlsx";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", token);

var response = request.GetResponse();
if(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(yourFile, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        dataStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
response.Close();
```

Comment: Well, it's not exactly that it's an old version, but really a weird one. It's used inside UiPath, an RPA system, and there are things that don't work as it should. For example, it's not in a method, but a kind of snippet, so I cannot use `await`. Also, I can define `System.Net.Http` as an assembly, but it seems like `HttpClient` is not the one that should be, as there are some compilation errors because it doesn't know `Content`.

Many thanks, but it doesn't work for me. The code I used "works", except because Excel doesn't like the format of the generated file. Any idea regarding that?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Added an amendment to the answer for WebRequest. The sample code provided worked for a test against my Tableau Online instance.

Comment: I like your solution better than what I did, thanks. But the result is the same . When I try to open the generated file, Excel says: "Excel cannot open the file 'testing.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.".

Comment: I've run it using VSCode instead of UiPath, just in case it was a problem with UiPath, but the result is the same. Weird, as it works if I call the API using Postman and then just save the response, without any further configuration/action. That means that the response is UFT-8, as it must be, but at any point, C# is converting it to another encoding. Or something.

Comment: Given that the above snippet worked for my and I can't reproduce, you may have a few debugging tasks ahead to narrow down the issue. Are you certain the supplied session token is valid (as they are very short lived)? If you debug the response, can you confirm that the response status code reflects a success? Is the file being written to disk the approximate size you'd expect compared to the known result? Does it open if you rename to .XLS? Does it work if you try exporting other tables, especially smaller ones?

Comment: [Imagine here a hysterical laughter and my head hitting the desk]

I was using the wrong endpoint for the API call . I was using the one to get the Workbooks in the site, instead of the one to download a view.

Thanks for your time. I cannot up vote the answer because I don't have enough reputation, but I'm going to mark this as the solution, even though my original snippet probably works (with the right endpoint, of course), because:
1. As I already said, I like it more than the original one.
2. For your time.
3. Your last comment triggered me to review the call.

Again, thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance! Got there in the end.